# Thank you. Then Thanks, at the end of e-mails?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning

At the end of e-mails, does it sound unusual to see "Thank you. Thanks," at the end of e-mail when you would like to reply to e-mails from colleagues who did something for you as below? How would you respond in this situation?

Thank you so much.

Thanks,

John

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The lower thanks is a *complimentary closing*, and is often a polite expression that does not have meaning beyond being polite. Hence it is generic, and the sender may end all his emails with *thanks*, irrespective of whether he is thanking the recipient. The line above is a sincere expression of thanking.

Answer (score 0):

I think having a "Thanks/Thank You" (or similar phrase) in the body of your message and the closing "Thanks" would be OK.

But the way you wrote:

> Thank you so much.
>
> Thanks,

both are really closing phrases. To me it seems repetitive unless you are really thankful.

So I would put the "Thank you so much." in the body and not a separate paragraph.

> Hello ...,
>
> Thank you so much for sending the items I requested.
>   So on and so forth...
>
> Thanks,